# Rave - Print band at the bottom of the page

Tags: delphi, rave-reports, quickreports

I recently recreated a report (which was previously made with quickreports) in my rave project. The quickreport had a band on it and this band had the AlignToBottom property set to true which makes the band always print at the bottom of the page. How do i get the same effect using rave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use a databand and set the position to absolute then measure how many cm down the page. Not ideal with different paper sizes etc but it works in a "controlled setting". Just make sure your region stops above the space allowed for the footer band or your details band may overlap the absolutely positioned band